# How to change the original value passed as props in vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Assume you have a `todo-list` component that will render the passed `todos` for you. where the `todos` is an `Ref` object.

```
<todo-list :todos="todos"/>
```

And the `todo-list` component also allow user to delete any of the passed todos.

But vue3 won't let us to mutate the `props.todos` object.

So the only way to do this is make a clone of `props.todos`, then if user click on the delete button, remove the item from that cloned one to update the view. But this approach won't make change to the original passed `todos` Ref object.

Another way to workaround this is emit an `itemDeleted` event from the `todo-list`, listen it from it's parent component, then remove the deleted item from the original passed `todos` Ref object in the listener.

But I want to keep all the logic inside of the `todo-list` itself, so I want to know if there is any way to change the original `todos` Ref object inside the `todo-list` component.

I know a better solution could be using `v-model:todo-list`, and emit a `update:todo-list` event to update the original `todo-list` Ref object. But I'm wondering if I can do this without the `v-model` directive.

Comment: please share the todolist component and its parent code

Answer (score 0):

Put the `todos` in separate file called `useTodo.js` which defines a composable function that could be reusable across multiple components without using any inner property or passing props :

```
import {ref} from 'vue'
const todos=ref([])

const useTodo= () => {

 setTodos(_todos){
       todos.value=_todos;
  }

return {todos, setTodos}
}

export default useTodo
```

then import it in both parent todolist components

parent component :

```
<todo-list />
...
import useTodo from './useTodo'
...

setup(){
    const {todos, setTodos}=useTodo();
    //use todos instead of your todos with ref

}
```

in todolist component :

```
...
import useTodo from './useTodo'
...

setup(){
    const {todos, setTodos}=useTodo();
     //use todos instead of props.todos

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Another way to workaround this is emit an itemDeleted event from the
> todo-list, listen it from it's parent component, then remove the
> deleted item from the original passed todos Ref object in the
> listener.

This is the ideal way of solving this type of problem.

The Vue philosophy is props down, events up. See:
https://medium.com/quick-code/vue-communication-patterns-an-intro-to-props-down-and-events-up-pattern-d53340d2c94

As components grow progressively more complex keeping the logic that actually edits the data in the same top level component that stores the data is preferable.